# .tz() in moment.js timezone does not convert time zones correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime, momentjs

I am having trouble when converting from time zone to time zone using moment.js.

This is my code:

```
convertSelectedTimeZoneToClients() {
    let timeZoneInfo = {
        usersTimeZone: this.$rootScope.mtz.tz.guess(),
        utcOffset: this.formData.timeZone.offset,
        selectedDateTime: this.toJSONLocal(this.formData.sessionDate) + " " + this.formData.sessionTime 
    };

    let utcTime = this.$rootScope.mtz.utc(timeZoneInfo.selectedDateTime).utcOffset(timeZoneInfo.utcOffset).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
    let con = this.$rootScope.mtz.tz(utcTime, timeZoneInfo.usersTimeZone).format();
    return con;
}
```

The user picks date, time and time zone from drop downs on client page. 
In timeZoneInfo object I am storing usersTimeZone (I want to be able to convert timezone that user selected on page and convert it to his local time zone).

For example user picks: 11/08/2016 01:30 and UTC+2 timezone and his timezone is UTC+1, than I want to show him in label: That is 11/08/2016 00:30 since UTC+1 is -1 hour comparing to UTC+2 timezone.

I store offsets for time zones in one object and those values are hard coded (`utcOffset: this.formData.timeZone.offset`).
Before I convert time form time zone to time zone I do this: get time zone -> convert to UTC time -> convert to user time zone.

What is happening is that utcTime variable has correct value. But when I pass that value and users time zone to .tz() function and using format() to get some readable value I get same time as utcTime like shown in picture:

[image]

I have read moment.js docs and by them this .tz().format() should do the work, but as you can see my result is: 2016-11-08T23:30:00+01:00.
So it gets that is should be incremented by 1 hour but how to accomplish to get: 2016-11-09T00:30 instead?

I have tried .format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm") as well same problem. When I use .local() function that should convert from utc time to specified time zone same problem is present.

Am I getting something wrongly? I am pretty sure that when you convert from 2016-11-08T23:30 UTC to UTC+1 it should be 2016-11-09T00:30, or one hour forward. Does someone sees something strange in this code?

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at `.utcOffset`

Comment: @PaulS. Thanks for responding. .utcOffset works correctly. It is used to convert selected time to UTC time, and the UTC time value is always good. Problem occurs when I want to convert from UTC to client time zone.